# Direction of electric field in the following cases?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, polarization, dielectric

[image]

In the above figure if applied electric field is at angle(but not normal) to the surface and is limited only to a specific region as shown, I believe the Electric field due to the induced  charges will be in opposite direction of the applied electric field as shown by dotted lines.

[image]
[image]

In the above two diagrams, electric field is present everywhere but at an angle(but not normal) to the surface as shown. I don't know(direction of induced electric field)if fig.2 is correct or fig.3. I don't understand if the induced electric field will oppose the applied electric field in opposite direction so that there is a possibility of reducing the potential energy as shown in fig.2 or if induced electric field will follow "least action path" to oppose the applied electric field as shown in fig.3 ?

Please help me understand.

Comment: Since rot(E) is not zero at the boundary between the "E only here" and "no E here" regions of Figure 1, this model requires some kind of time-varying magnetic B-field.
Alternatively, it would be quite difficult to achieve the setup in Figure 1 in a real experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that surface is conductor.Induce Charges will arrange themselves like that So that Electric Field inside a conductor is 0.(for conductors first one is correct )As it's a dielectric i think second option is correct.As negative charge will attract themselves towards left and positive charge will repel away making electric field like figure 3

Comment: So does that mean least action path is not always correct?

Comment: Another doubt I have in this is - if the induced electric field is in the exactly opposite direction to the applied then in boundary condition of electric fields, the tangential components should be discontinous. Am I missing out something ? Please help me out

Comment: induce field will not be not exactly opposite

Comment: Thank you so much sir! In a conductor (for the situation in question) what I don't understand is whether the electric field should follow least action path, which will not cancel out the field or should it follow to cancel out the field, so that the conductor will achieve least energy? In both cases least action is there. Which least action will have priority?

Comment: i mentioned that for conductors E=0 induce charges inside a conductor  will produce equal opposite electric field so that E=0

Comment: Yes sir I understood your point. I wanted to know if that's really necessary because electric field could take least path as well.

Comment: Should I ask it as a new question ?

Comment: sure , why not ?

Comment: @TrilokGirishKamagond Can u provide me with a source where where it's said electric field take least path

Comment: I don't have any reference actually. I just thought based on the least action postulate.

Comment: Maybe that's the problem because it's no where written they do follow least action postulate

Comment: Yes it is not mentioned anywhere. So it's confusing for me to decide

Answer (score 0):

There will be no strict boundary to the polarization effect. The effect will decrease as you go far from the marked region and when you've moved sufficiently far away within the di-electric material the  effect will be negligibly small.

The molecules (within the material) not in the region affected by the field will assume an opposite polarity to that of the field and this effect will decrease as you move away and finally reduce to zero.

If it were a metal the electric field lines would have entered and left the metal at right angles to make the tangential component zero because of redistribution of charges and if it were not so the charges would continue to move but here the charges can't move around hence the tangential component may not necessary be zero.

Comment: Actually I have assumed uniform electric field.

Comment: Well... Then it's just as fine

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I understand the fig1 properly. But what about the fig2 and fig3? How will the induced field will be? Can you also mention the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

Your diagrams are not drawn correctly, since they do not satisfy boundary conditions for electric field at a dielectric interface.

From Maxwell's equations and the constitutive relations, tangential electric field is continuous across a dielectric interface, and the condition for normal electric field at the interface is $\epsilon_1 E_{n1} = \epsilon_2 E_{n2}$. From these relations it follows that

$\frac{E_{n2}}{E_{n1}}=\frac{\tan \theta_1}{\tan \theta_2}=\frac{\epsilon_1}{\epsilon_2}$

where $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are the respective angles from the surface normal. For $\epsilon_2 \gt \epsilon_1$, $\theta_2 \gt \theta_1$, and the field lines inside bend away from the normal at the interface.

In addition, finding the fields requires solution of a boundary value problem that inculdes superpositon of the imposed field with that due to the polarization of the dielectric. From the simpler textbook problem of a point source near a plane dielectric interface, easily solved by the method of images, it is seen that, near the interface, polarization bends field lines outside the dielectric toward the normal. Polarization always reduces the field inside the dielectric, and for $\epsilon_2 \gg \epsilon_1$, field inside is very small, and the field outside approaches that near a conducting surface.

The [dielectric sphere](https://www.physics.wisc.edu/undergrads/courses/fall2016/322/322-2016-lec15_more_dielectrics_+_practice_problems.pdf) in a uniform field is another problem that can be solved analytically, and shows similar field behavior.

I don't know of any easy solution for the configurations you posed, and it is likely that a numerical solution is necessary, particularly for finite dielectrics and non-uniform electric field.

Comment: Thank you for giving such a insightful answer. I now understand the importance of boundary conditions. I am new to this.

Comment: Can you if possible provide a reference where I could learn how to solve ?

Comment: Actually assuming the bending of electric field lines at the surface, can you also tell in what way the polarization fields will be? That is what I want to understand